# angularjs javascript does not load in view

Tags: angularjs

Javascript is not being loaded within ui-view. The widget on the INDEX PAGE loads fine, the widget on the HOME PAGE does not. Is there a way maybe refresh the view without actually causing a refresh? Or any other suggestions?

```
-----------------------------------------------
INDEX PAGE:

<div class="page-content-wrap">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="widget widget-default widget-carousel">
            <div class="owl-carousel" id="owl-example">
                <div>
                    <div class="widget-title">Total Visitors</div>
                    <div class="widget-subtitle">27/08/2014 15:23</div>
                    <div class="widget-int">3,548</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="widget-title">Returned</div>
                    <div class="widget-subtitle">Visitors</div>
                    <div class="widget-int">1,695</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="widget-title">New</div>
                    <div class="widget-subtitle">Visitors</div>
                    <div class="widget-int">1,977</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ui-view="main">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
-----------------------------------------------

HOME PAGE VIEW:

<div class="well">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="widget widget-default widget-carousel">
            <div class="owl-carousel" id="owl-example">
                <div>
                    <div class="widget-title">Total Visitors</div>
                    <div class="widget-subtitle">27/08/2014 15:23</div>
                    <div class="widget-int">3,548</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="widget-title">Returned</div>
                    <div class="widget-subtitle">Visitors</div>
                    <div class="widget-int">1,695</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="widget-title">New</div>
                    <div class="widget-subtitle">Visitors</div>
                    <div class="widget-int">1,977</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ui-view="main">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
-----------------------------------------------

APP.JS

stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        module: 'public',
        url: '/home',
        name: 'home',
        views: {
            'main@': {
                templateUrl: 'home.do',
            },
        },
        data: {
            displayName: 'Home',
        }
    })
-----------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance for you assistance.

Comment: Does the javascript search for the widget markup on page load? If so, then the view in Home Page does not exist on the page when initialized. You would have to run the function again.